# Does SAP Allow VPC Peering Between Our Own VPC and SAP Cloud Platform's VPC?

Tags: amazon-web-services, sap

We have an application deployed on SAP Cloud Platform's Cloud Foundry environment that needs an ElastiCache cluster to operate.
Can we set up a peering connection between our VPC and the VPC where SAP's Cloud Foundry is deployed so that our application can access ElastiCache without having to be routed over the internet (currently we are forced to use a NAT instance)?

To clarify: I'm interested in knowing if anybody has successfully done this/knows for a fact it's possible; not whether it's technically possible or not to set up peering between two VPCs in general (I know it is).

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to reach out to the party that you want to peer with? After all, even if someone here has done it, that doesn't help you in any way to actually do it. I'd much prefer to get first hand confirmation from the actual party then second hand, anecdotal information from the internet.

Comment: @joeqwerty I'd prefer it that way too, but I do not have access to a support plan and things move very slow. I need answers fast (matter of days instead a matter of weeks) and was hoping that I could at least uncover whether it's possible at all.

Comment: @Peter you should know whether or not you have admin access to the SAP account? If you do you can try to set up vpc peering. If you don’t you can’t. Simple as that :)

Comment: @MLu, I dont have admin access, but others may (will also take time to check). Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

VPC Peering works on an **Invite-Accept** model. If you have admin privileges in the target SAP VPC and can accept the VPC Peering invite from your VPC you should be able to set up the peering.

If you don't have admin privileges there then you can't set up the peering yourself. You may ask the admin (SAP?) to accept the peering invite.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thank you @MLu. Can you confirm that you know for a fact that SAP allows their customers to do this or were you just explaining in general how VPC peering would work, making the assumption that SAP is willing to peer with their customer's VPCs? My question was mainly about whether SAP's willingness, not the technical feasibility. Apologies if this wasn't properly articulated.

Comment: @Peter I have no idea what SAP’s policies are. I was explaining it from the AWS perspective. Talk to SAP, I’m sure you’ve got some support there.